# how to compare current and old password both are same or not before updation in DB using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I used this HTML for developing Form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('patients/change_patient_password'); ?>/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('patientDiseasesId'); ?>" class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-body">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Current Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Current Password">
                                <?php $pass = form_error('password'); if(isset($pass)): ?><span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span><?php endif; ?>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">New Password </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="password_confirm" placeholder="New Password">
                                <?php $pass_confirm = form_error('password_confirm'); if(isset($pass_confirm)): ?><span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('password_confirm'); ?></span><?php endif; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">ReType New Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="password_confirm2" placeholder="ReType New Password">
                                <?php $pass_confirm2 = form_error('password_confirm2');  if(isset($pass_confirm2)): ?><span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('password_confirm2'); ?></span><?php endif; ?>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-actions">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn green">Update Password</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </form>
```

also please have a look my code controller.

```
public function change_patient_password($patientId){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|is_unique[patients.password]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'New Password', 'required|matches[password_confirm2]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm2', 'ReType New Password', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->change_patient_password_form();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('patients_model');

        $data['password_updated'] = $this->patients_model->change_patient_password_model($patientId);

        if($data['password_updated']==true){
        $data['success']=true; 
        $data['main_content']= 'change_patient_password_form';

        $this->load->view('includes/patient_template',$data);
        }else{
        $data['error']=true; 
        $data['main_content']= 'change_patient_password_form';

        $this->load->view('includes/patient_template',$data);

            }

    }
```

here is the final model code

```
public function change_patient_password_model($patientId){


        $data = array(
           'password' => md5($this->input->post('password_confirm'))
        );

        $this->db->where('patientDiseasesId', $patientId);
        return $this->db->update('patients', $data);

        }
```

Comment: Stored passwords shouldn't be available to decode. Therefore it is recommended to use stored hash string that can't be reverted to plain text, but only compared to input if used same function as for initial input. MD5 is insecure method these days, so you should use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or similar method instead. I found [hashids](http://hashids.org/) could be useful.

Comment: will you please send me proper link or code where you use this.

Comment: You can use, for example, [this library](https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt). After loading library, you are able to use `hash_password` and `check_password` methods.

Comment: you know how to insert urdu language data in php mysql database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77081/discussion-between-tpojka-and-muddasir-abbas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using "is_unique" in your form validation. Will each password be unique?

How I would do this, is to query the DB before we update it, and check if the passwords match. Like so.

```
public function change_patient_password_model($patientId)
  {
    // Get this users info
    $query = $this->db->get_where('patients', array('patientDiseasesId' => $patientId));
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      // We have the patient, so check if the passwords match
      $current_password = $query->row('password');
      $inputted_password = md5($this->input->post('password_confirm'));

      if( $current_password != $inputted_password)
      {
        // They are not the same, so update it...
        $data['password'] = $inputted_password;
        $this->db->where('patientDiseasesId', $patientId);
        return $this->db->update('patients', $data);
      }
      else
      {
        // They are the same...
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // No patients with this ID
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I would do. Easy and efficient.

Comment: thanks what about controller and view how to call in controller and send into view.

Comment: I have 3 input fields in form. 1) current password which is stored in db. and 2nd and 3rd new password and verify password. now let me know if user input wrong current password then show error not update. but it is still updating.

Comment: Thanks it is working. just one more thing. if i comment this $data['password'] = $inputted_password; it shows error mean showing you must have to pass something like that. may i know why ?

Comment: Sorry, I have only just seen your replies. If you comment out that line, it will thrown an error as the $data array you're updating will not exist.

Comment: no worries, but why this show error because i am not using this in view. will you please explain may be i am not getting your point.